# Trying to click a Button called “Book Now” with Selenium and Java but get “could not be scrolled into view”, then ‘"this.js" is null” errors

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit5

I am attempting to create a test script that books an event… but I am trying to select and click the “Book Now” button on this page..
https://www.trybooking.com/events/landing?eid=757231&

clicking on the "Book Now" button should take the booker to the sessions page..
https://www.trybooking.com/book/sessions?eid=757231

Instead my code causes a Junit/Java exception...

I have made may attempts to select the button and click on it so that it goes to the sessions page.. with the following... [these have been commented out in the code]...

```
    String url = "https://www.trybooking.com/events/landing?eid=757231&";
    myDriver.get(url);
    //WebElement we = myDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//span/button[text()='Book now' and @class='btn btn-secondary text-uppercase btn-landing go-to-session']"));
    //WebElement we = myDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//span/button[text()='Book now']"));
   // WebElement we = myDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//span/button[text()='BOOK NOW']"));
    //WebElement wb = myDriver.findElement(By.xpath ("//*[contains(text(),'Book now')]"));
    //WebElement wb = new WebDriverWait(myDriver, Duration.ofSeconds(50, 1)).
    //WebElement wb = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Book now')]")));
    //WebElement wb = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Book now') ]")));
    //WebElement wb = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-secondary text-uppercase btn-landing go-to-session']" )));
    //wb.click();
    //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-secondary text-uppercase btn-landing go-to-session']" ))).click();
    
    //WebElement wb = myDriver.findElement(By.xpath ("//button[@class='btn btn-secondary text-uppercase btn-landing go-to-session']"));
    //WebElement wb = myDriver.findElement(By.xpath ("//div[@class='pl-0 mr-3 sticky-btn-wrapper'] and button[@class='btn btn-secondary text-uppercase btn-landing go-to-session']"));
    //WebElement BookNowButton = myDriver.findElement(By.xpath ("//div[@class='pl-0 mr-3 sticky-btn-wrapper']//button"));
```

My latest attempt and selenium code...My selenium code to select this is ...

```
    // added at the start of the Junit ...  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) myDriver;
@DisplayName("TC03: Book into an event (ADVANCED TASK)")
         void Test3() 
     // commented out.. throws Exception
     {
        //myDriver.get("https://www.trybooking.com/book/search");

        
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(myDriver, Duration.ofSeconds(10, 1));
        myDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        
        String url = "https://www.trybooking.com/book/search";
        myDriver.get(url);

        myDriver.findElement(By.id("initSearchKeywordId")).click();
        myDriver.findElement(By.id("initSearchKeywordId")).sendKeys("Makerspace Docklands - Safety Induction");
        myDriver.findElement(By.id("initSearchButtonId")).click();
     
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("pre-load-spinner") ));
        WebElement we = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='search-heading' and starts-with(@id, 'newSearchNavigateHeadingEventId')]/h2[contains(., 'Makerspace Docklands - Safety Induction') and contains(@ng-bind, 'EventDisplayName')]")));
        we.click();
        
       
        // now to click on the book Now button on the "Makerspace Docklands - Safety Induction" page 
        
        WebElement BookNowButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath( "//div[@class='pl-0 mr-3 sticky-btn-wrapper']//button"  )));
        //This will scroll the page till the element is found       
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",BookNowButton);
        BookNowButton.click();
    // more code to follow
    }// close void Test3()
```

I get the following error message…

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor.executeScript(String, Object[])" because "this.js" is null
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This code won't even compile because `js` is not defined. Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code, properly formatted. Also post the full error message, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Think this maybe the issue, your declaration has not been constructed, hence "this.js" is null:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) myDriver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",BookNowButton);
```

As you usually have to define/construct use of JavascriptExecutor as:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",BookNowButton);
```

Try the following to avoid "this.js" is null, assuming that in your code it should be:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) myDriver);
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",BookNowButton);
```

If you still have the issue, try to troubleshoot using:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) myDriver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",BookNowButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

Null point exception happens when driver instance is not interact by selenium in every class

Solution - define webdriver driver in global variable

**WebDriver driver;**

Comment: Hello I have this code..
`// Update this class name by replacing S3214321 with your student ID`
class TryBookingTest_S9905648 
{
    WebDriver myDriver;

    
.......
....'

Comment: where you define webdriver as global variable ?

Comment: It is defined as a global variable.... as "WebDriver myDriver"...